# JWPlayer: Removing listeners on remove event

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I have written a piece of code to unregister from JWPlayer events

`jwPlayer().on('remove', function(e){
    // taking the lisenters off
    jwplayer().off('error');
    jwplayer().off('levelsChanged');
 });`

Problem is these "off" calls work, if they are called before remove is called on the player but after remove is called, the execution stops.

```
jwplayer().remove()
```

So my question is does "remove" removes the listeners and I dont have to do it manually or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using jwplayer().remove() resets the DOM to its original state and removes all listeners. You may want to take a look at the API documentation here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_reference/

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to make those calls manually as `.remove()` completely removes the player instance from the page.